# <select> onchange with jQuery 1.3.2 and IE7

Tags: jquery, select, binding, bind, onchange

I have this typical problem with select.  First let me make it clear that I am running `jQuery 1.3.2` which I know is pretty old but due to some reasons I cannot update it.  My problem is with `jQuery 1.3.2` and `IE7`.  Now the problem is I have the below select box...

```
<select class="myclass">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
    <option value="monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
</select>
```

and the problem is that with my script this select is replaced with same select which is retrieved from an ajax call.  But since its replaced the `change` event does not work on it anymore.  I can use `live()` but that does not work in IE7 as of `jQuery 1.3.2`.  I also cannot use `deligate()`, so is there any method by which i can achieve successive change events after the select has been replaced?

If not is there any way i can bind the `.change()` function to the same element after the ajax call?

Here's my script...

```
$('.myclass').change(function(){
    //other code
    $.post(document.URL,data,function(){
        //other code
        //[[here on success I want to bind the same code again on my class so it will be called the next time]]
    });
});
```

Is rebinding the function an option here? I am looking for a solution besides adding `livequery`.

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/hycxJ/)  If you run this in IE9 it will work but not in IE7 and IE8

Comment: instead of replacing the select element, why not just wipe out the option elements and put in the new ones ?

Comment: @code90 thought of that but its a complicated section with many includes and calculated by php so doing that will be problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can replace the `option`'s of `select` box instead of replacing itself.

`change` event not supported by `$.live()`:

> In jQuery 1.3.x only the following JavaScript events could be bound:
>
> **click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove,
>   mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup.**

See http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live.

You can use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

#### *One thing you can do is, after replacing the `select`, you can rebind the `change` event to that `select`*.

For example:

```
function replaceSelect() {
    var select = this;
    //other code
    $.post(document.URL,data,function(data){
        $(select).replaceWith(data.html);
        $('.myclass').change(replaceSelect);
    });

}
$('.myclass').change(replaceSelect);
```

Comment: the replace code comes in html with the above select and other page data.

Comment: @LoneWOLFs one thing you can do is, after replacing the `select`, you can rebind the `change` event to that `select`.

Comment: @LoneWOLFs haha.. feeling happy

Comment: yep a lot i am seriously against using this old lib of jQuery but I am told not to change it as it would break other code else I had other logic for this :)  Anyways thx a lot for the great help.